# How to set up Seq logging Dashboard for a particular event with Timing information?

Tags: seq-logging, datalust-seq

I am using Seq logging in my .NET application.
I have the blow log appearing multiple times,

```
 Execute Owin configuration completed in 56.1 ms
```

[image]

The time varies for each time the app starts up.
The timing info is available as a property in Properties Array.
[image]

I want to create a dashboard showing the timing for each startup. How can I do that?

UPDATE:
Events like these,
[image],

But, based on the query, my chart looks like,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your query to:

```sql
select max(@Properties['1'])
from stream
where @EventType = 0x8308754F
group by time(1h)
```

And execute it, you can then press the "Add to dashboard" button just to the right of the filter box and you should get a chart with the info you want.

Comment: I updated my question with the chart, I want each event to print on the chart. Here it looks like only the max one is appearing.

Comment: Is it possible to change Y axis scale/values?

Comment: I want all @Properties['1'] values to appear on the dashboard.